# extract multiple substr and match & replace using perl

Tags: perl, substr

I need to extract multiple substrings at fixed positions from a line and the same time replace whitespaces at another position.

For example, I have a string '01234567890   '. I want to extract characters at positions 1,2,6,7,8 and the same time if position 12, 13 are whitespaces, I want to replace them with 0101. It is all position based.

What is the best way to achieve this using perl ?

I can use substr and string comparison and then concatenate them together, but the code looked rather chuncky....

Comment: Please clarify "the same time if position 12, 13 are whitespaces, I want to replace them with 0101." You listed two positions, but 4 replacement chars, for starters. Do you want to replace them input string, or in the extracted data?

Comment: I meant to say 'replace them with 01'. Either way is fine.

Comment: That doesn't help me at all. Replace each of them with `01` or 12->0, 13->1?   Do you want to replace them input string, or in the extracted data?

Comment: 2 whitespaces -> 01. Extracted data.

Comment: Thanks, though I see amon gave a good answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably split (or: explode) the string into an array of single chars:

```
my @chars = split //, $string; # // is special with split
```

Now we can do array slices: extracting multiple arguments at once.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(all);

if (all {/\s/} @chars[12, 13]) {
   @chars[12, 13] = (0, 1);
   my @extracted_chars = @chars[1, 2, 6..8];
   # do something with extracted data.
}
```

We can then turn the `@chars` back into a string like

```
$string = join "", @chars;
```

If you want to *remove* certain chars instead of extracting them, you would have to use `slice`s inside a loop, an ugly undertaking.

#### Complete sub with nice interface to do this kind of thing

```
sub extract (%) {
   my ($at, $ws, $ref) = @{{@_}}{qw(at if_whitespace from)};
   $ws //= [];
   my @chars = split //, $$ref;
   if (all {/\s/} @chars[@$ws]) {
      @chars[@$ws] = (0, 1) x int(@$ws / 2 + 1);
      $$ref = join "", @chars;
      return @chars[@$at];
   }
   return +();
}

my $string = "0123456789ab \tef";
my @extracted = extract from => \$string, at => [1,2,6..8], if_whitespace => [12, 13];

say "@extracted";
say $string;
```

Output:

```
1 2 6 7 8
0123456789ab01ef
```

Comment: `@chars[1]` is second, not first

Comment: @ikegami I know, therefore the comment with the "nullth" element. The association beween *index 8* and *eight* is more obvious than with *ninth*.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the comment, but it really doesn't justify the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is two separate operations, and should be coded as such. This code seems to do what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'abcdefghijab  efghij';

my @extracted = map { substr $str, $_, 1 } 1, 2, 6, 7, 8;
print "@extracted\n";

for (substr $str, 12, 2) {
  $_ = '01' if $_ eq '  ';
}
print $str, "\n";
```

**output**

```
b c g h i
abcdefghijab01efghij
```